# $n$ persons who make telephone calls

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Lets say we have $n$ persons and everybody knows one specific thing which the other persons do not know. When two of the $n$ persons telephone they share their knowledge about the specific thing. How many calls are needed before everyone knows all the specific things?

I think it goes in the following way (but this seems to me too easy): Person 1 needs to make $n$ phone calls until he knows everything. Person 2 need to make n-1 phone calls...

After $(n-1)!$ phone calls they knwo everything.

Comment: You can easily check that if $n=3$, two phone calls are not enough: you need $3$.

Comment: Are you sure that a person only shares their special info and not everything they currently know?  If so then $(n-1)n/2$ is certainly best. But if a person shares everything they know up to that point, we can do much better.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Ok, the upper bound is $2(n-1)$, do we have any choice to get the precise optimal solution?

Comment: "they share their knowledge about the specific thing" About the single specific thing each one knew originally, or all the knowledge they currently have?

Comment: @Alkibiades Actually the upper bound is $2n-3$: Let $a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ call $a_n$, after which $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ know everything. Then let $a_1, \ldots,a_{n-2}$ call $a_n$.

Comment: It should mean that a person shares everything he knows up to that point, sorry for the confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n\ge4$ the answer is $2n-4$ as shown by [Brenda Baker and Robert Shostak](http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/PUZZLES/gossips.pdf), Gossips and telephones, Discrete Math. 2 (1972), 191-193. "Other solutions have been given
independently by R. T. Bumby and by A. Hajnal, E. C. Milner and E. Szemerédi."